# Replacing a React.createClass with extends React.Component

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, components

Facebook has suggested the future removal of React.createClass completely in favour of ES6 classes. I'm now beginning to go through my react.js classes and replace them with the now accepted `class MyClass extends React.Component` syntax. However, I don't think I'm quite there yet on some things. I have coded the following API mount and gulp doesn't seem to like this particular module when loading: `Cannot find module '.components/ticker-trader' from '/.../src'`.

My particular class is outlined as:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class TickerTrader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      $.get("api_url", function(data) {
        this.setState(data),
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default TickerTrader;
```

Could anyone outline where exactly this has gone wrong...I'm sure it is something simplisitic. I have attempted to fix this by using the documentation but I don't seem to be getting anywhere...

Comment: Could you provide your gulpfile, or the relevant section. It looks like it might be a paths issue?

Comment: @MarkWilliams This is the only component which has this issue. My `index.js` file contains: `import TickerTrader from '.components/tradingdesk-ticker';` with the above class being in a file with the name `tradingdesk-ticker.js` in the `src/components` folder. Not sure why this isn't working...

Comment: @MarkWilliams If this helps gulp spits out these errors:    `4:26  error  Unable to resolve path to module '.components/tradingdesk-ticker'  import/no-unresolved
   4:26  error  Missing file extension for ".components/tradingdesk-ticker"        import/extensions
   6:1   error  Expected exception block, space or tab after '//' in comment       spaced-comment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file paths.

`Cannot find module '.components/ticker-trader' from '/.../src'`

That looks wrong.

Instead of `.components/ticker-trader` it more than likely should be looking for `./components/ticker-trader`.

Comment: That has fixed that particular issue. I may need to open a new ticket because I have a new error - `Unexpected token (14:6) while parsing file: /Users/.../src/components/tradingdesk-ticker.js`. Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen the syntax error now, there shouldn't be a comma after `this.setState(data)` - really basic stuff I should see. Apologies.